# Is it necessary for a distance measure used in clustering to correspond to some valid vector space?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have defined an distance measure based on some properties of points. But I'm not even sure that it corresponds to a valid distance in some vector space. Is this a necessary condition for clustering ? If yes, how do I check that it's a valid distance in some vector space. Just like Mercer's theorem can verify that the kernel is an valid cross product in some valid vector space, are there any such tests for distance ?

Comment: What clustering algorithm(s) do you have in mind? Most need the "distance" to be a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) but not all of them need it to be a Euclidean metric. Some distances, such as path distances along directed graphs, do not even require the "distance" to be symmetric (which is one of the axiomatic properties of a metric).

Comment: @whuber actually I found surprisingly few algorithms that are flexible with respect to the distances that really require metric properties. For example k-medoids: does it require triangle inequality for convergence or not? The only one that comes to my mind spontaneously is the M-tree/Cover-tree family of indexes; these have an explicity requirement for triangle inequality. And "identity of indiscernibles" virtually does not exist in databases: we always have to expect "duplicate" records to happen.

Comment: @Anony I do not understand that database remark: if two records are duplicates, then they represent the same thing and they necessarily have the same distances to all other objects. Regardless, much of the literature distinguishes a "dissimilarity" function from a true distance function. Many clustering algorithms are based on dissimilarity, not on distance--which I guess is a partial answer to the present question.

Comment: Well, they still are not identical. They have different object IDs, so in order for things to be a true metric, they would need to have a distance larger than 0. Of course you can map objects to their equivalence class and get back a distance. But it's a difference between mathematical view and data analysis, that we do need to take into account that two objects may have the same attribute values, yet are separate observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the actual algorithms. There is no general rule.

Some will require metric properties, other just assume you have some dissimilarity, and can trivially be rewritten to use similarity measures instead.

For example DBSCAN (see "Generalized DBSCAN") doesn't actually use the distances, but is only interested in a binary threshold decision to discern "near" and "far" objects. Metric properties allow the algorithm to run faster, by performing this selection efficiently.

k-means on the other hand is actually not even using distance, but as it tries to minimize *variance*, it assigns each objec to the mean with the smalles "sum of squared deviation". And the sum of squared deviations is the squared Euclidean distances. As taking the root of this value, this means each object is assigned to the closest mean by Euclidean distance. It is not mathematically correct to use other distances with k-means (although it may work, at least if the *mean* function minimizes the distances; otherwise k-means may no longer converge!) - the reason why in k-means we assign points to the nearest mean is *not* to minimize distances, it is to minimize the total sum of variances. This ensures convergence: reassignment reduces variances, and recomputing the means also reduces variances. As there are only a finite number of assignments, we must at some point stop.

On a side note, try to approach clustering from the "knowledge discovery" point of view, not from "learning". You want to discover something new with clustering, not reproduce something you already know; so it is pretty much the exact opposite of learning labels.

Comment: Because you appear to contradict yourself concerning K-means, let's clarify the point here: the variance in any K-means problem is a positive-definite quadratic form and thereby defines a valid distance (which can be considered Euclidean: this property is essential to efficient implementations of the algorithm). Thus K-means actually *is* using a fairly restricted form of distance.